# Visual Studio and OpenCV fails to link cv.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I downloaded the latest OpenCV-2.4.2.exe and unpacked it. Then I opened a project in visual studio 2010 and pointed it to the include and lib folders that it needs to build.

In my case, the lib folder is in \opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib which is different than the instructions online. This folder seems to contain a compiled version of everything. However, when I build my project, I get

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cv.lib'

cv.lib is nowhere to be found.

Is there something else that needs to be compiled?

Comment: Except for pointing to the lib folder, do you actually include the libs? Also, have you included OpenCV in your PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the issue.

In stdafx.h I had to comment out:

```
//#pragma comment(lib, "cv")
//#pragma comment(lib, "cxcore")
//#pragma comment(lib, "highgui")
```

which were trying to load cv.lib, etc. My guess is this was correct for previous openCV version but isn't valid for 2.4.2. Then I had to add

```
D:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_core242d.lib;D:\opencv\build\x86\vc10 
\lib\opencv_imgproc242d.lib;D:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui242d.lib; 
D:\opencv \build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_objdetect242d.lib;
```

to my project in the Linker->Input->Additional dependencies part.

I tried the staticlib folder and x64 but this is what worked for me on Windows 7 64-bit.

Hope this helps someone else (I've seen similar issues other people had).